# Jenkins Workflow: Multibranch plugin checkout to subdirectory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

How can I checkout from SCM in a Jenkins Workflow: Multibranch job into a subdirectory of the job workspace? Are there any option to this:

```
checkout scm
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
dir('subdir') {
    checkout scm
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that cause the repo to be checked out twice? Once in the workspace root and once in workspace/subdir?

Comment: Yes, it does, @Caleb. The problem here I believe is that the multibranch pipeline checkout, the one performed to simply scan the Jenkinsfile, does a full checkout but into the workspace, not into a subfolder.

Comment: You can skip the default checkout so you only check it out once `options { skipDefaultCheckout() }`

Answer (score 1):

When use Multibranch plugin in declarative pipeline you should avoid double checkout repository use options `skipDefaultCheckout`.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label "something"
  }
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
  stages{
        stage('Checkout repository') {
            steps {
                dir('subdir') {
                    checkout scm
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

p.s. I think clean repository is good practise `bat "git clean -fdx"` or `sh 'git clean -fdx'`

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2020, there is no way to do so. You can upvote the request:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62082?jql=labels%20%3D%20multibranch